# Decision boundary and weight vector in SVM

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, svm

I have some confusions regarding SVM as I don't have much of a mathematical background.

Let the equation of hyperplane(in any dimension) be `w'x+b=0`, now I know that weight vector `w` is orthogonal to this hyperplane.

Is the equation `w'x+b=0` just a general equation of a hyperplane having nothing to do with a SVM, i.e., if `w` and `x` are general vectors, then will any hyperplane of the form `w'x+b=0` will have the vector `w` orthogonal to the hyperplane?

Consider the scenario below:

[image: SVM]

Now while minimizing the objective function `0.5*||w||^2`, we take the constraints to be `w'x+b>=1` for examples in `class 2` and `w'x+b<=-1` for examples in `class 1`. So if I change these equations to `w'x+b>=2` and `w'x+b<=-2`, will I get a classifier with even larger margin? If, then why don't we use it? If not, then why not?

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for the [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any hyperplane fits that equation, and `w'` will be orthogonal.

No, you won't get a margin twice as large: the SVM algorithm finds the largest margin.  What you'll get is `b` having coefficients twice as large as the previous one.